# Tratamento JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Através de JQUERY, preciso fazer uma requisição via `POST` onde vou obter um `JSON` com um token.
O retorno JSON que obtenho após enviar o POST é esse:

```
{
    "Token": "e27bb0a7-e65b-4cc3-a82e-7a2a3c26a248",
    "Codigo": 0
}
```

Minha dúvida é:
Como faço a leitura desse token?
Um analista me informou que devo fazer algo mais ou menos assim:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 var settings = {
   "async": true,
   "crossDomain": true,
   "url": "https://siteexemplo.br/login/geraTok",
   "method": "POST",
   "headers": {
     "content-type": "application/json",
   },
   "data": {
     "RA": "12345",
     "senha": "xxx"
   }
 }
  
 $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
   console.log(response);
 });

});
```

Mas e depois disso? Onde está o token?
Como passo ele para uma variável por exemplo?

Obrigado pessoal!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{ "Token": "e27bb0a7-e65b-4cc3-a82e-7a2a3c26a248", "Codigo": 0 } é a resposta do servidor em `JSON`.
```

`response` pega essa resposta em forma de objeto, então basta armazenar...

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
          var token = response.Token;
          console.log(token);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

O retorno dos dados apareceram na variável `response` que é o parâmetro da função quando ela terminar (done), você pode simplesmente usar a notação de `ponto` para acessar as chaves de um `json`, veja:

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response.Token); // pega o token retornado do json
  console.log(response.Codigo); // pega o código retornado do json
});
```

Comment: fala @Rafael Acioly, Acredito que acessar as chaves de um JSON não seria um termo correto, JSON é para transferência somente, ao ser interpretado pelo javascript já pode ser tratado como objeto, vlw!